# Blocking inside of StreamObserver.onNext()

Tags: java, grpc

I couldn't find anything in the GRPC documentation about this. Does GRPC expect my implementation of `StreamObserver.onNext()` to be non-blocking? What are the implications on GRPC if it does block (e.g. rejects new requests, queues up new requests, etc..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can block if you need to block.

Since the callbacks for the RPC are considered non-thread-safe, blocking will delay other callbacks until you return. That includes `setOnReadyHandler` and `setOnCancelHandler` in `ClientCallStreamObserver` and `ServerCallStreamObserver`.

In streaming RPCs, gRPC automatically requests another message after you return from your `onNext()`, so if you block gRPC will avoid receiving too many more messages. gRPC will still allow some messages to be buffered, however.

Blocking has no impact on new RPCs.